# JQuery Table Manipulation Inserting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

What I want to do, in short, is from `$(this)` being a table row, find the next table row with a class of "example" (not necessarily a sibling).

I.E. use `next()` to find the next row with a class of "example" which isn't a sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>One</td></tr>
    <tr class="current"><td>Two</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Four</td></tr>
    <tr class="target"><td>Five</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Six</td></tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var current = $('.current').next();
while(current.size() && !current.hasClass('target')) {
    current = current.next();
}
current.css('color', '#0f0');
```

OR

```
$('.current').nextAll('.target').last().css('color', '#0f0');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're building those `<tr>`s from strings, you could do something like that:

```
var x = '';
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    x += '<li>Test ' + i + '</li>';
}
$(x).appendTo('#test');
```

So instead of inserting the table rows one by one, put them together as one string, make a jQuery object from that string and attach that to your table.

This also helps you with performance, since you edit the DOM only once.

Comment: The rows have to be added seperately unfortunately. I've rephrased the question as I probably overly explained lol. Thanks anyway though